# Slimming down pop up code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am still learning the ropes with jquery / javascript so please excuse my very messy code. I have set up an overlay function but have had to repeat it for each link. What i'm looking for is a way to slim down this code so that I hdon't have to keep repeating the open and close buttons for each link. Sorry if this doesn't sound clear enough. The fiddle is below. Thanks !

http://jsfiddle.net/olichalmers/a2p3J/1/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

var content = $("#content");
var logo = $("#logo");
var links = $("#links");
var social_orb = $("#social_orb");
var links_exit = $("#linksexit");
var introintro = $("#introintro");
var overlayintro = $("#overlayintro");
var exitintro = $("#exitintro");
var comingfrom = $("#comingfrom");
var overlaycomingfrom = $("#overlaycomingfrom");
var exitcomingfrom = $("#exitcomingfrom");
var nikkisays = $("#nikkisays");
var overlaynikki = $("#overlaynikkisays");
var exitnikkisays = $("#exitnikkisays");
var mobile_social = $("#mobile_social");
var mobileintro = $("#mobile_introintro");
var mobilecomingfrom = $("#mobile_comingfrom");
var mobilenikki = $("#mobile_nikkisays");

introintro.on("click", function () { content.fadeOut(50); setTimeout(function () { overlayintro.fadeIn(50) }, 100) });

mobileintro.on("click", function () { content.fadeOut(50); setTimeout(function () { overlayintro.fadeIn(50) }, 100) });

exitintro.on("click", function () { overlayintro.fadeOut(50); setTimeout(function () { content.fadeIn(50) }, 100) });

comingfrom.on("click", function () { content.fadeOut(50); setTimeout(function () { overlaycomingfrom.fadeIn(50) }, 100) });

mobilecomingfrom.on("click", function () { content.fadeOut(50); setTimeout(function () { overlaycomingfrom.fadeIn(50) }, 100) });

exitcomingfrom.on("click", function () { overlaycomingfrom.fadeOut(50); setTimeout(function () { content.fadeIn(50) }, 100) });

nikkisays.on("click", function () { content.fadeOut(50); setTimeout(function () { overlaynikki.fadeIn(50) }, 100) });

mobilenikki.on("click", function () { content.fadeOut(50); setTimeout(function () { overlaynikki.fadeIn(50) }, 100) });

exitnikkisays.on("click", function () { overlaynikki.fadeOut(50); setTimeout(function () { content.fadeIn(50) }, 100) });
```

})

Comment: why have you made separate variables inside the code , you may directly use them. Moreover you can do something like this $("abc,xyz").on("click",function(){content.fadeOut(50); setTimeout(function () { overlaynikki.fadeIn(50) }, 100) });

Answer (score 2):

You can seperate the selectors by comma, for example:

```
$('#introintro,#mobile_introintro').on("click", function () { 
    content.fadeOut(50); setTimeout(function () { 
        overlayintro.fadeIn(50) 
    }, 100) 
});
```

Comment: That's close, but if you look some of the click functions are slightly different... for instance `exitintro` fade outs the `overlayintro`.

Comment: yes but you can merge out the similar one to shorten your code and make the code more clear

Comment: @DaveZych I think based on your current HTML, you need to do the same for other selectors as well

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys, I appreciate it. 

@DaveZych - Based on your suggestion, how would this work because as Aman states, the individual links fade in and fade out the relevant overlays. If you group them into one click, surely you can't select the specific overlay to appear?